# How to implement call recording with android ndk

Tags: android-ndk, audio-recording, phone-call, opensl

I want to record calls with android NDK. Previously i was using sdk and recording calls but in few specific phones and new released phones at (API Level 24/Nougat) or higher  call isn't recording.

Comment: The Java APIs end up calling native functions too, so there's no reason why switching to the NDK should give you a higher success rate. Some devices simply don't support voice call recording.

Comment: @Michael I am also looking for NDK implementation are there any references, please help